# How to different the two appState in react-native: app go to background, or app ask permission

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, frontend

I am developing a bank react-native app, try to implement a feature that every time the app goes from background/inactive to active status, users need to verify TOUCHID.

What I did is to check the AppState:

```
    if (OldappState.match(/inactive|background/) &&
      nextAppState === 'active'
    ) {
      checkLocalAuth()
    }
```

It works fine, but I find a funny problem: when app ask permission, the AppState will become `inactive`, when user granted the permission the AppState becomes `active`, that is exactly the same with the behavior of the action described above.

But I don't want to ask for TOUCHID when asking permission, so how to differ the two situations?

Comment: have you found any solution to this problem?